# Reflection with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, entity

I have table name as string in my hand. Help to access the entity using reflection. My query is,

```
TestEntities entity = new TestEntities();
var countryList = entity.GetType().GetProperty("Countries").GetValue(entity, null) as 
  typeof(ObjectSet).MakeGenericType(Type.GetType("CRUDService.Country"));
```

I queried country table using reflection and try to converting result as Country type. But it's not working. Kindly help me to convert specific type at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Expression `var value = obj as`**`typeof`**`(YourType)` is invalid; `as` keyword cannot be followed by operator `typeof`; you actually need to reference the type without the help of `typeof`

Your only option is to treat it as a non generic `ObjectQuery` since you don't know the type at code time:

```
TestEntities entity = new TestEntities();
var countryList = 
  entity.GetType().GetProperty("Countries").GetValue(entity, null) as ObjectQuery;
```

Be sure this will return an `ObjectSet<Country>`. The problem you face now is that you loose the generic benefits of `ObjectSet<T>`. You can solve this later by creating a generic extension method that can be used once your code knows about the actual ElementType of your IQueryable.

```
public static ObjectSet<T> Cast<T>(this ObjectQuery objectSet)
{
  if(!(objectSet is ObjectSet<T>))
    throw new Exception("Invalid instance passed or entity type specified");

  return objectSet as ObjectSet<T>;
}
```

Use `var countries = countryList.Cast<Country>();` to get your generic `ObjectSet<>`